# Duplicate detection in Azure Storage Queue

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage

I want to know if there is any elegant way to ensure that Queue always have distinct messages (nothing related to Duplicate Detection Window or any time period for that matter) ?

I know that Service Bus Queue provides session concepts (as I mentioned Duplicate Detection of Service Bus Queue won't help me as it depends on time period), which can serve my purpose, but I don't want my component's dependency on another Azure service, just because of this feature.

Thanks,

Comment: For reference [Azure Service Bus Queues vs Azure Storage Queues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-azure-and-service-bus-queues-compared-contrasted)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is not possible to do reliably.

There is just no mechanism that can query a Storage queue and find out if a message with the same contents is already there or was there before.  You can try to implement your own logic using some storage table, but that will not be reliable - as the entry into the table may succeed and then entry into the queue may fail - and now you would potentially have bad data in the table.

Your code should always assume that it can retrieve a message containing the same data that was already processed.  This is because messages can come back to the queue when workers that are working on them crash or take too long.

Comment: Indeed, you need an idempotent process

Answer (score 1):

You can use Service Bus. Is like Azure Storage Queue but it allows messages of 256Kb-1MB and makes duplicate detection

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately Service Bus doesn't have a cross platform emulator. Which is tedious to work with on UNIX environments.